# Bluetooth disabled on startup

Tags: bluetooth

My iMac only has a Bluetooth keyboard and mouse.

I turned Bluetooth off and can’t find a way to restart with Bluetooth enabled.

Comment: Are these Apple keyboard and mouse, or third-party? The Apple keyboard takes a USB to Lightning cable, and will work without Bluetooth. Other keyboards may have a USB port.